# How can I configure a Ubuntu LAMP web server with permissions like CPanel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, security

I know how to set up a LAMP stack on Ubuntu pretty well for a single website / single user, but I'd like to allow multiple users to host multiple sites on a single server.

This is for different departments in an organization, so I don't think anyone using the server would be malicious, but I would like to try to separate out access anyway.

I like how most CPanel is set up so that:

1. Users can't see each other's files
2. Apache / PHP runs as the user and not `www-data`
3. Scripts can't access things outside of the home directory (except for maybe `/tmp/`)
4. Users can connect via FTP but are limited to their home directories
5. Users can access the box via jailshell

I dont actually need a control panel like CPanel, I just want the behaviors / features mentioned above.

In doing research on how to accomplish those things I've found:

1. Set file permissions correctly and also ftp access only (or maybe jailshell)?
2. `suPHP`, `suPHPexec`, or `Apache suEXEC` ?
3. Something like `open_basedir`?
4. `vsftp` seems like the standard / most common thing for this
5. I see that there is `jailkit` for Ubuntu - not sure how common it is.

I've been reading up on `suPHP`, `suPHPexec`, `Apache suEXEC` - but:

- I am unclear about which one might work best with Ubuntu
- I can't tell which ones might be most commonly used

I have also seen some discussion on `mod_fcgid` and `PHP-FPM` which I'm not sure are right for any of the requested features - I know they help with memory management for PHP.

- Can those two tools be used to have a script "execute as the owner" ?
- Are they commonly used with Ubuntu?
- Are they stable enough to run with a production server? (I've seen some complaints especially regarding `PHP-FPM`)

Ideally I'd like to go with the the ones which are most commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Control Panel have a look at:

```
Webmin/Virtualmin - looks most promising.
ispCP - looks really slick, but seems to still be in development (maybe stalled?)
vhcs - also looks slick, not sure about the licensing though.
Penguinator - looks to be very actively developed, the guys that run the project do seem a little disorganised: judging by their Web site.  You'll also need to get the source code from SVN as they don't appear to have an official release.
eBox - more of a general configuration tool, looks pretty though. You might be able to use it somewhere else.
```

Do let us know how you get on, am interested to know what you choose and how well it goes. Good luck!

Comment: well, these look interesting but I don't think they do what I'm asking for - I did menton `I dont actually need a control panel like CPanel, I just want the behaviors` - like how to get apache/php to running as the user on ubuntu (the most common / popular way)? :\